# returning alias using minus in sql query fails

Tags: sql, alias

I have a problem with an sql query that will not work if I try to use alias (scount, samount). The query runs ok without alias and it also work fine using only the first (scount) but as soon as I add the second one (samount) the query fails to execute. I assume this is related to that I do a minus query for some reason.

Can anyone help me resolve this so that I can return the values with the aliases.

```
select count(t.invoiceID) scount, sum(amount) samount  -
IFNULL(
(
select sum(p.amount) as pamount  
    from invoice t,  invoiceFactoring ift, InvoiceType it, Payment p                    
    where t.issuerID = 38
    AND ift.invoiceID = t.invoiceID
    AND t.invoiceID = p.invoiceID
    AND it.invoiceTypeID = t.invoiceTypeID
    AND now() > date_add(t.invoiceExpiryDate, INTERVAL 45 DAY) 
)
,0)
  from invoice t,  invoiceFactoring ift, InvoiceType it
  where issuerID = 38
  AND ift.invoiceID = t.invoiceID
  AND it.invoiceTypeID = t.invoiceTypeID
  AND now() > date_add(t.invoiceExpiryDate, INTERVAL 45 DAY)
  AND t.disabled = 0 
  AND it.typeCategory = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alias goes **after** calculation.

```
SELECT 1 blah - 2 <--- wrong
SELECT 1 - 2 blah <--- correct
```

P.S. clarification

your query is essentially this:

```
SELECT ... scount, ... samount - IFNULL(...)
FROM ...
```

just replace it with

```
SELECT ...scount, ... - IFNULL(...) samount
FROM ...
```

and accept the answer if it helps you because you will hardly get another until you start accepting.

Comment: hmm ok make sense, not sure I understand how to make that work in my query though. Maybe you (or someone else) can be more specific on how I can have the query return: scount, samount. (please :-) )